# Why google.script.run does not work from HTML?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I create a spreadsheet that acts as a form. the user fills detail in the cells and when he finishes, he clicks on a submit button, a signature pad opens, he signs, and then clicks submit the signature is saved in a folder in google drive.

the code worked just fine, but now for some reason when the HTML file opens the script ends, and the `google.script.run.saveImage(bytes)` doesn't execute the rest of the code in the `.gs`.

The strange thing is that I think that the `google.script.host.close()` works because the HTML window gets closed when clicking on the Submit button. I added console.log in between the lines to see if the code there executes but I don't see anything in the execution Log.

Here is my code and the HTML file:

Code:

```
//a function that being called after the technician finished the RMA form and sends the new data to the database.
function rmaCmUpdate()
{
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var emptyCriticalCells = false;
  var currentRow = 14;
  //checking if the technician filled all the necessary fileds in the form
  while (thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,2).isBlank() == false)
  {
    if (thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,9).getValue() == "" || thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,11,1,3).isChecked() == false || thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,11,1,3).isChecked() == null || thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,15,1,5).isChecked() == false || thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,15,1,5).isChecked() == null || thisSheet.getRange(currentRow,35).isChecked() == false || thisSheet.getRange("rmaDecision").getValue() == "" || thisSheet.getRange("technicianName").getValue() == "")  //if one or more of the critical feilds are empty
    {
      emptyCriticalCells = true;
      break;
    }
    currentRow++;
  }

  if ( emptyCriticalCells == true) // if one or more of the critical feilds are empty a messaga appear
  {
    var buttonPressed = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('One or more of this fields are not filled (Final RMA decision:,Technician name:,Visual Inspection:,Power ON Check(AC):,Leds Check:,Driver Test:,Dimmer Card Functionally:,Script Test:,Power (W) Test;,Wiring connectivity:,Sealing:).' + ".\n" + 'All those fields should be filled, are you sure you want to continue?',SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  if (buttonPressed == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.NO || buttonPressed == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CLOSE) //if the user preesed NO or the 'X' button it will stop the code.
        {
          return;
        }
  }

  signatureForm(); //calling the function that takes the signature and executes the rest of the code.
}


//the electronic signnature functions
function signatureForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('signature').setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Please sign below to complete the submit');
}


function saveImage(bytes){
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var rmaNumber = thisSheet.getRange("RMA").getValue();
  var technicianName = thisSheet.getRange("technicianName").getValue();
  var formNumber = thisSheet.getRange("formNumber").getValue();
  var bytes = bytes.split(",");
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(bytes[1]), 'image/png');
  blob.setName(technicianName + " sign -RMA:" + rmaNumber + "-form:" + formNumber);
  var newSignatureId = DriveApp.getFolderById("1jEC8R7tK_XTTRcjOboqq-MqW6Pkz_CE2").createFile(blob).getId();
  var newSignatureLink = DriveApp.getFileById(newSignatureId).getUrl();
}
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/willowsystems/jSignature/master/libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>

Please draw your signature on the signature pad below: 

<div id="signature"></div>

<img id="rendered" src="">

<script>
  $("#signature").jSignature({
    'background-color': 'transparent',
    'decor-color': 'transparent'
  });

  function renderSignature(){
    
    $("img#rendered").attr("src",$('#signature').jSignature('getData','default'));
    var bytes = document.getElementById('rendered').src
  console.log(bytes)
  google.script.run.saveImage(bytes)
  console.log("i was called 1")
  google.script.host.close()
  console.log("i was called 2")
  }

  function saveImage(){ //This sends the image src to saveImages function
  var bytes = document.getElementById('rendered').src
  console.log(bytes)
  google.script.run.saveImage(bytes)
  }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="renderSignature();"/>
</script>
</html>
```

I hope someone can help me fix it because I tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work :(

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue is due to that `google.script.run` and `google.script.host` work with the asynchronous process. So, in your situation, how about modifying `google.script.run.saveImage(bytes) google.script.host.close()` to `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).saveImage(bytes)`?

Comment: Script run is running asynchronously, that's why next code after it can run immediately

Comment: @Kos I also think that it is the answer to this question.

Comment: I modified my script as you suggested instead of 'google.script.run.saveImage(bytes)' i wrote 'google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).saveImage(bytes)', and removed 'google.script.host.close()'. but it does not work. after i click submit the HTML window close but nothing happens (the saveImage function does not execute). @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from your replying. So in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I modified my script as you suggested instead of 'google.script.run.saveImage(bytes)' i wrote 'google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()).saveImage(bytes)', and removed 'google.script.host.close()'. but the code does not work. the function 'google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).saveImage(bytes)' is not executing for some reason. after the HTML window opens the script ends. @Tanaike